# Triangle Perimeter and Area Calculator

Tags: javascript, html

I need to create a simple triangle perimeter and area calculator working with browsers. I need a simple html javascript code where users input the 3 sides lenght and they receive the perimeter and area of the triangle.
Something like this but for triangle:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Circle Area</title>
</head>
<body>
  <script language="JavaScript">
    function CalculateArea(){
        var radius =document.form1.txtRadius.value;
        document.write("<P>Circle Area is" + (radius * radius * Math.PI) + "</p>");
        document.write("<P> The circumference of the circle is " + (2 * radius * Math.PI) + "</p>");
    }
    </script>
    <form name=form1>
       Enter the radius of the circle:
       <input type="text" name="txtRadius" size=10>
       <br>
       <input type="button" value="Calculate" onClick='CalculateArea();'>  
    </form>
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Can anybody help?

Comment: You can replace the formula used there for the formula needed for the perimeter and area

Answer (score 0):

For perimeter:

```js
function perimeter() {
  var sideA = document.getElementById("sideA").value;
  var base = document.getElementById("base").value;
  var sideB = document.getElementById("sideB").value;
  var perimeter = parseFloat(sideA) + parseFloat(base) + parseFloat(sideB);
  var result = document.getElementById("result");
  result.innerHTML = "Area is " + perimeter;
}
```

```html
<span>Side A:</span>
<input id="sideA" type="text" size=10>
<span>Base</span>
<input id="base" type="text" size=10>
<span>Side B:</span>
<input id="sideB" type="text" size=10>
<br>
<input type="button" value="Perimeter" onClick='perimeter();'>
<p id="result"></p>
```

You can replace what is needed to replace to get the area of a triangle.